How do I make my webapp classes available to a jar on Jetty's classpath? (Jetty 10+)
My webapp is a WAR file deployed on Jetty 10. I want to use Java SPI to define an interface that end users can implement. The idea is that end users can implement the interface and put a jar in Jetty's lib/ext folder, and my webapp will pick it up and use it at runtime with ServiceLoader.
This does not work however because of WebApp ClassLoader isolation. When the ServiceLoader tries to load the user's implementation, it throws NoClassDefFoundError on my webapp's interface that the user is implementing.
I need a way to tell Jetty to allow the interface in my webapp to be visible to the jar placed in lib/ext.
@Jaokim Erdfelt describes how you can "poke holes" in the WebApp ClassLoader isolation by using a context xml file and the addServerClass method (Jetty 9).
See: External jar available to all Jetty web services
I.e. the xml for Jetty 9 looked like this:
<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
  <Call name="addServerClass">
    <Arg>-com.corp.common.</Arg>
  </Call>
</Configure>

With Jetty 10, however, the method signature changed and now takes a Server argument in addition to the package name pattern:
public static void addServerClasses(Server server, String... pattern)

How do I call addServerClasses in my context XML for Jetty 10+ that properly passes in the new Server argument?
Also, do you think my approach for solving this is correct in general?
I've tried many ways of getting the Server argument but can't get it to work. It's not clear to me how to get the new Server argument and pass it in to the addServerClasses method in my context xml.

Another approach I've tried is adding a mywebapp.mod file to /modules and a mywebapp.ini file to the `/start.d' folder. The .mod file supports the following lines. e.g.:
[lib]
webapps/mywebapp.war

[ini]
jetty.webapp.addServerClasses+=,-com.corp.common.

But I can't get that to work either. In any case I would prefer the simplicity of a simple context xml file next to my war in the webapps folder if I could get that to work.
